# Can gpasswd add non-local users to local group?

Tags: users, group, active-directory

We use CentrifyDC in our organization.

I have a local group to which I want to add AD users.

```
# getent passwd aduser
aduser:x:12345:12345:AD User:/home/aduser:/bin/bash
```

As illustrated, `getent` successfully resolves the user; but `gpasswd` fails to recognize its existence when adding to a local group:

```
# gpasswd -a aduser localgroup
gpasswd: user 'aduser' does not exist
```

Hilariously, it doesn't care to check when *deleting* a user from a group:

```
# grep ^localgroup: /etc/group
localgroup:x:2468:aduser
# gpasswd -d aduser localgroup
# echo $?
0
# grep ^localgroup: /etc/group
localgroup:x:2468:
```

I'm successfully using a `sed` command for adding users, but wondered if there's some special combination of options to `gpasswd` to convince it that actually, yes, AD users do indeed exist.

Comment: Side note: I don't believe I'm the first person to ask a question in the context of Centrify, but this is where the **centrify** tag was created.

Comment: Maybe try the fully-qualified name (`user@domain` or something like that). `gpasswd` works just fine with non-local users (I use it often with LDAP) - as long as  the user details are available via the `getpwnam(3)` function (there's an example in [the manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwnam.3.html) you can use to test that function directly).

Comment: Thanks @muru ! I compiled up the example, and it works fine. Evidently `gpasswd` is doing unnecessary checks with its `-a` option, _and not_ `-d`. It's like the maintainers have gone out of their way to create an unworkaroundable bug. Thanks for the sanity check!

Comment: @muru - the example even works using UPN, SAM name, CN, and GECOS. ... And even double- or single-quoted `"domain\samname"`

Comment: The `-d` thing is a bit arguable - it's quite possible you have already deleted the user and are cleaning up the groups after. So you're saying the usernames work with `getpwnam` but not `gpasswd`?

Comment: @muru - That's correct. `getpwnam()` and the example from the manpage correctly retrieve the user. `gpasswd` does not (and has no apparent options to work around the issue). My last resort is to go back to manually manipulating `/etc/group`'s membership.

Comment: Which is fairly strange, since `getpwnam` is exactly what `gpasswd` uses for the check: https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blame/master/src/gpasswd.c#L251 I wonder if you can get more useful information using `strace` on `gpasswd`.

Comment: @muru - `strace` tells me it's loading `nsswitch.conf` where I only have `centrifydc files` for `passwd`, `shadow`, and `group`. It's loading `/lib64/libnss_centrifydc.so.2` which in turn reads `/etc/centrifydc/centrifydc.conf`; so everything's _there_, it's just not working.

Comment: @muru - I tried adding as a non-root, 'Centrified' AD user, and it told me `gpasswd: Cannot determine your user name.` so this is even more fundamental. I'll take a look at the source as you did. I may be incorrect, but I think it _worked_ in RHEL5... I'll go check. (just checked) No I'm wrong. Same failures in RHEL5.

Comment: @muru - I think I have it! There's a repeated comment where `getpwnam()` is used: `/* local, no need for xgetpwnam */`. So it appears to me that `gpasswd` is artificially restricting itself to local-only names (and in that case, is the fact it resolves LDAP users a bug?) If I get a good slice of time to follow up, I'll try compiling one up with `xgetpwnam()` instead.